# Is there a smooth function which behaves like $x^n\sin(\frac{1}{x})$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

The function $x^n\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is finite-order differentiable at $x=0$, and near $x=0$ it vanishes infinite times but not identically.

I wonder if there is a smooth function like this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2} \sin(1/x)$ will be smooth at $0$, and will vanish infinitely many times in a neighborhood of zero.

Comment: It might be worth adding that one cannot do better in the sense that one cannot have an analytic function, as no non-zero analytic function can  have an accumulation point of roots in the domain.